# Openstack - how to assign floating IP pool to specific tenant

Tags: ip, openstack, floating

In OpenStack (regardless of particular release/version), can you assign a specific floating IP pool to specific tenants? i.e. **Pool 1** gets used by Tenant 1 and **Pool 2** gets used by Tenant 2?

I need a way to distinguish clients from on a network layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the command `nova floating-ip-associate` or if you are using Neutron, try the following:

Select a floating IP address for the new VM instance to use.
Use the `neutron floatingip-list` command to display floating IP addresses for the tenant you chose in Step 1. If necessary, use the `neutron floatingip-create` command to create a floating IP address for this tenant. Note the ID of the floating IP address.

Associate the floating IP address with the new VM instance.
Use the `neutron floatingip-associate` command to associate the floating IP address from Step 6 with the new VM instance.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E54155/clicreatevm.html

You can check Openstack docs, it explained there just share with the exact command line. But be careful when associate by command line by practice I find its better to de associate by command line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So does that mean, tenant 1 will NOT be allowed to use any of IP addresses reserved for tenant 2?

Comment: Yes it will be reserved and you need to go back and release it when you want to use it again